# How to write String Iteration with Map Put operations in Java 8?

Tags: string, lambda, java-8, hashmap

I am trying to convert following code into Java 8::

```
String s = "12345";
Map<Character,Integer> map = new HashMap<Character,Integer>();
for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
 char c = s.charAt(i);
 if (map.containsKey(c)) {
   int cnt = map.get(c);
   map.put(c, ++cnt);
 } else {
   map.put(c, 1);
 }
}
```

I tried and found following way to iterate:

```
IntStream.rangeClosed(0, s.length).foreach(d -> {
      //all statements from char to map.put
}) ;
```

I am not sure whether this is correct way to do it.

Comment: Or use `toMap` with merge function: `s.chars().mapToObj(i->(char)i).collect(Collectors.toMap(Function.identity(),v->1,Integer::sum));`

Comment: Consider staying with the loop: `for(int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) map.merge(s.charAt(i), 1, Integer::sum);`. Of course, you can also use `IntStream.range(0, s.length()) .forEach(i -> map.merge(s.charAt(i), 1, Integer::sum));` instead. But that’s not a real improvement.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do this:

```
s.chars()
  .mapToObj(x -> (char) x)
  .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.counting()));
```

- `.mapToObj(x -> (char) x)` is necessary because `.chars()` gives you a stream of ints, but in order to use `groupingBy` you need to work with objects, not primitives
- `groupingBy` receives a function to get the key to group by and a `Collector` implementation
- `Function.identity()` is just a function that returns whatever element it is passed to it
- `Collectors.counting()` is a collector that counts

Comment: Mind that this will create a `Map<Character,Long>`. You’d need, e.g. `Collectors.summingInt(ch -> 1)` instead of `Collectors.counting()` to get a `Map<Character,Integer>`.

Comment: Nice, I wasn't aware of that method. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `groupingBy()` and `counting()` collectors:

```
String s = "12345";

Map<Character, Long> map = s
        .chars()
        .mapToObj(i -> (char) i)
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.counting()));

System.out.println(map);
```

Unfortunately, there seems to be no convenient way to get a `Stream<Character>` from a string, hence the need to map to an `IntStream` using `chars()` and then using `mapToObj()` to convert it to a character stream.